# XMLHttpRequest returns the complete page that the data was requested from

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

So here is my request in javascript:

```
var requestGenre = new XMLHttpRequest();
        requestGenre.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
            {
             //loadMovieList(this.responseText);
             console.log(this.responseText);
            }
        };
        requestGenre.open("POST", "MovieGenre.php", true);
        requestGenre.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        requestGenre.send("requestedGenre="+e.target.innerText);
        }
```

The Problem:
In *this.responseText* i do get the exact data that I need but only after the complete html of the *MovieGenre.php* page.

I don't understand what im missing I've done the same request in other pages and it worked.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the expected outcome?

Comment: can you show the moviegenre.php

Comment: @mplungjan the expected outcome is :

*all html from MovieGenre.php*
followed by
*the data i requested*

Comment: can it be because im not rendering the page again?

Comment: It is completely unclear what the actual vs the expected output is. You request a page and you get the page. What is supposed to happen? responsetext is text - do you need HTML?